# Show and hide button when value is true in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs-scope

I got an application which uses the `'oidc-client'` module, which redirects and if logged in properly in that website I return the value `{{auth?.loggedIn}}` in my HTML. This value can either be true or false.

What I´m trying to do is to show a second button only when the value `{{auth?.loggedIn}}` is true. And when the value is false. Been trying with the ng-hide method and then function to check, but doesn´t do anything.

Here´s my HTML part:

```
<button (click)="onLogin()" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">SSO Login</button>
Currently Logged In?  {{auth?.loggedIn}}
Logged in as:  {{currentUser?.profile?.email}}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href='/secondpage'">Go to second page</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `ng-if='true/false'` do not use `{{}}` in directive

Comment: Thanks! And how would I link the button object with the value from `auth?.loggedIn`? Sorry I´m not great at angular (actually first project).

Comment: may be ```<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" ng-if='auth?.loggedIn' onclick="window.location.href='/secondpage'">Go to second page</button>``` if  ```auth?.loggedIn``` is available